# Selection creating New Folder In Root/sdcard/storage

Tags: java, android

I am allowing user to choose folder before downloading files.

This is what is did to give user an option to select folder.

```
 private void pathlist(String basepath) {


        File folderlist = new File(basepath);

        File[] folders = folderlist.listFiles();
        Log.e("Base", basepath);

        for (File folder : folders) {
            if (folder.isDirectory()) {
                folist.add(folder.getName());
            }
        }


        foladap = new Foladap(DownloadFolderOptions.this, folist);
        listView.setAdapter(foladap);
    }
```

where  `basepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();`

using above I get list of folders at Internal Memory.

But problem is when I select any folder like Movies, the final selected is

```
/storage/emulated/0/Movies
```

and System create a new folder at selected path instead of folder shown in list.

How to handle this.?

pls guide.

if I select Movies folder using Asus File Manager, the path shows as Root/Sdcard/Movies. what is this path and how it is different then what I selected as got after selection.

Comment: `But problem is when I select any folder like Movies, the final selected is

/storage/emulated/0/Movies`. That is correct.

Comment: `and System create a new folder at selected path `. Impossible. If the folder already exists you cannot create yet a folder with the same name.

Comment: `instead of folder shown in list.`. ??? Movies? But who is creating a folder? Or who wants to create a folder? You only want to select one i understood. All makes no sense.

Comment: `if I select Movies folder using Asus File Manager, the path shows as Root/Sdcard/Movies`. Terrible file manager. It is probab!y indeed /storage/emulated/0/Movies. I hate those file manages that obscure the real path. Most file explorers do now adays. Terrible.

Comment: There is code in another class which create folder using mkdirs.

Comment: Now this is really problem that if there is a folder at /storage/emulated/0/Movies, then why mkdirs is making another folder at /storage/emulated/0/storage/emulated/0/Movies.

Comment: this is how path is checked and created    File folder = new File(rpath);
            if (folder.canExecute()) {
                System.out.println("  Folder Found");

            } else {
                folder.mkdirs();
            }

Comment: `There is code in another class which create folder using mkdirs` Well... shouldnt you post that code then?

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/storage/emulated/0/Movies`. Well... look... look closely! You can clearly see that you double the path! And if you post code then do not use a comment for that!